# What is the correct way to toggle this innerHTML with a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically when the div shows or hides, I want to respectively toggle the `innnerHTML` with a "+" (when hidden) and a "-" (when shown). It works initially, but not subsequently.

```
$('#summary-head').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#summary-bod').slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
    if(document.getElementById('summary-head').innerHTML = "-  Professional Summary") {
        document.getElementById('summary-head').innerHTML = "+  Professional Summary";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('summary-head').innerHTML = "-  Professional Summary";
    };
});
```

What would the correct way to do this be? This isn't working.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you should use it everywhere and not mix native object with jQuery objects so `$('#summary-head')` and not `document.getElementById('summary-head')`

Comment: You're not comparing any values in your `if`, you're currently assigning values.

Comment: `=` != `==` but besides that, actually log, think, and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your code.  Comparison statements should use "==", not "=".  It's a really common mistake to try to use "=" for comparisons--don't!

Try the following:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id = "summary-div">
  <span id ="summary-head">+  Professional Summary</span><br/>
    <div id = "summary-bod">
    This is a summary body
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('#summary-head').click(function(evt) 
{
  evt.preventDefault();
  $('#summary-bod').slideToggle(1000);
  $(this).toggleClass('close');

  if (document.getElementById('summary-head').innerHTML == "-  Professional Summary") 
  {
    document.getElementById('summary-head').innerHTML = "+  Professional Summary";
  } 
  else 
  {
    document.getElementById('summary-head').innerHTML = "-  Professional Summary";
  };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Also just a style note--and this is personal preference--IMHO the code would be cleaner if you used a boolean flag to indicate whether or not to display the "+ text" or the "- text"; set/clear that flag in your IF statement and make your decisions based on the flag, not the inner html of a span/label/UI element.  Another programmer might come along later and change the text of your UI element (e.g. "Executive Professional Summary" instead of "+ Professional Summary") without realizing you've got code elsewhere that depends on the text.  Changing text in the UI shouldn't break code.  Just my two cents' worth.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you just use CSS:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.wrapper').click(function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('switch');
     });
});
```

```css
.wrapper .content2{
   display:none;
}

.wrapper.switch .content2{
    display:block;
}

.wrapper.switch .content1{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content1">-  Professional Summary</div>
  <div class="content2">+  Professional Summary</div>
</div>
```

The jquery just adds or removes a css class and the css rules do the rest

Comment: This is the solution I was thinking of, however I would refactor it so only the +/- toggle, without repeating the following string.

Comment: Which is fine @Taplar I was aiming at broad strokes

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to put the `+`/`-` icon within it's own `span` in the element. Then you can provide a function to `text()` which updates the new setting based on the current. Something like this:

```js
$('#summary-head').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#summary-bod').slideToggle(1000);
  $(this).toggleClass('close').find('span').text(function(i, t) {
    return t.trim() == '+' ? '-' : '+';
  });
});
```

```css
#summary-bod { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="summary-head">
  <span>+</span>
  Professional Summary
</div>
<div id="summary-bod">
  Foo bar
</div>
```

Note that when using jQuery it's best to stick with the methods it exposes instead of mixing and matching with native methods. In this case they were redundant anyway as you already have a reference to the clicked element through the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning a value to innerHTMl in if statement. Try this code:

```
$('#summary-head').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#summary-bod').slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).toggleClass('close');
    if(document.getElementById('summary-head').innerHTML === "-  Professional Summary"){
        document.getElementById('summary-head').innerHTML = "+  Professional Summary";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('summary-head').innerHTML = "-  Professional Summary";
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A small twist on Liam's answer using just css.  The `~` says to look for a following sibling (in)directly.

```css
.hide { display: none; }

.contentState:checked ~ .collapse {
  display: inline-block;
}

.contentState:not(:checked) ~ .expand {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <input type="checkbox" id="professionalSummaryState" class="contentState hide" style="display:none;">
    <span class="collapse hide">-</span>
    <span class="expand hide">+</span>
    <label for="professionalSummaryState">Professional Summary</label>
  </div>
</div>
```